# Help with Regex patterns

Tags: regex

I need some help with regex.

1. I have a pattern AB.* , this pattern should match for strings
   like AB.CD AB.CDX (AB.whatever).and
   so on..But it should NOT match
   strings like  AB,AB.CD.CD ,AB.CD.
   AB.CD.CD that is ,if it encounters a
   second dot in the string. whats the
   regex for this?
2. I have a pattern AB.** , this pattern should match strings like 
   AB,AB.CD.CD, AB.CD. AB.CD.CD but NOT
   strings like  AB.CD ,AB.CDX,
   AB.whatever Whats the regex for
   this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Clarify your use of . and () please; these are special in regexes but it looks like you want to match periods and you're just using () in your examples as a delimeter.  Is this correct?

Comment: sorry not delimiters , but simply examples..
you can consider them as AB , AB.CD.CD , AB. CD , AB. CD.CD

Comment: Why not update the question with the correct details rather than sprinkle the details in the original question and the comments section?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got globs not regular expressions. Dot matches any char, and * makes the previous element match any 0+ times.

1) `AB\.[^.]*`
Escape the first dot so it matches a literal dot, and then match any character other than a dot, any number of times.

2) `"^(AB)|(AB\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$"`
This matches `AB` or `AB` followed by `.<stuff>.<stuff>`

Comment: I tried with globs , but it also gives true for both case AB.* and AB.**
for any string matching AB.whatever ,
But my requirements are somewhat refined for * and **

Answer (score 2):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ contains lots of useful information for learning about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports negative lookahead you might try something like:

```
^AB\.[^.]+$
^AB(?!\.[^.]+$)
```

(or

```
^AB\.[^.]*$
^AB(?!\.[^.]*$)
```

if you want to allow AB. )

Answer (score 0):

I don't find you're question entirely clear; please comment here (or edit your question if you can't add comments) if I'm getting this wrong but what I think you're looking for is:

1) matching strings "AB.AnyTextHereWithoutDots" but not "AB" or "AB.foo." etc

If so a matching regex would be:

```
"^AB\.[^.]*$"
```

2) matching "AB" or "AB.something.something" with either none or two or more dots

If so a matching regex would be something like:

```
"^AB(\..*\..*)?$" or "'^AB\(\..*\..*\)\?" (depending on the nature of your regex engine)
```

As [Douglas suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486730/help-with-regex-patterns#486735) matching with globs would likely be easier.

And as [spdenne suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486730/help-with-regex-patterns#486746), find a good regex reference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in vim. Here is the sample data:

```
AB.CD
AB.CDX
AB.whatever
AB
AB.CD.CD
AB.CD.
AB.CD.CD
```

Here is my regexes

1. This captures all lines starting with AB and then expects a literal dot, and then filters out all lines that has a second dot.

   ^AB\.[^.]*$
2. This captures all lines that is just an AB (the part before the pipe) or lines that start with AB that is followed by two literal dots (escaped with a backslash)

   ^AB$\|^AB\..*\..*$